# Cannot successfully install plot Haskell

Tags: haskell, plot, installation, cabal-install, hmatrix

I'd like to do some graphing in my Haskell program, but when I try to install plot I get the following error.

```
Preprocessing library plot-0.2.3.4...

lib/Graphics/Rendering/Plot/Figure/Simple.hs:37:8:
    Could not find module ‘Numeric.Container’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

lib/Graphics/Rendering/Plot/Types.hs:25:8:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Packed.Vector’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

lib/Graphics/Rendering/Plot/Types.hs:26:8:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Packed.Matrix’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
plot-0.2.3.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Following [this issue](https://github.com/amcphail/plot/issues/13) I updated hmatrix to version `0.17.0.1` but still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install both together, or did you re-install `hmatrix`?

Comment: I reinstalled just `hmatrix`

Comment: Try opening a new sandbox (`cabal sandbox init`) and then running `cabal install hmatrix-0.17.0.1 plot-0.2.3.4`....

Answer (score 2):

Are you managing the project with `cabal`, or are you just installing into the global package space?

I would move to either using `cabal` or `stack` to manage the dependencies.
FWIW I've verified that `plot-0.2.3.4` will compile with `hmatrix-0.16.1.5` using the stack resolver `lts-3.7` so I don't think it's a problem with `hmatrix`.

If you are using cabal, post your cabal file and we can figure out how to make it work. Otherwise, I would recommend creating a stack project, eg.

- run `stack new project-name`
- edit `project-name.cabal` and add `plot` to the `build-depends:` fields
- run `stack build`

Answer (score 0):

```
   Configuring hmatrix-0.16.1.5...
    setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.4.0-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.2: Missing dependencies on
    foreign libraries:
    * Missing C libraries: blas, lapack
```

Found the libblas library I needed via:

```
sudo apt-cache search blas | grep dev
```

from: https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/blob/master/INSTALL.md#linux

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev libgsl0-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-base-dev

setup: The pkg-config package 'cairo' version >=1.2.0 is required but it could
not be found.
```

After some putzing around on the wiki pages for gtk2hs

```
sudo apt-get install libghc-gtk-dev
```

Now it should install successfully.

```
stack install plot
```

Intermediate errors are from me re-attempting `stack install plot`. These instructions assume Ubuntu 14.04 but you can translate what packages you need to Mac OS X / Windows.

As the other poster said, this was with the 0.16 version of hmatrix.